# NameLookup does not pull Phone number

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I have 2 fields that looks for username, the gets the email address and phone number from user's person document.

Creator_Email: @NameLookup([NoUpdate]; @UserName; "OfficePhoneNumber")
Creator_Ext: @NameLookup([NoUpdate]; @UserName; "OfficePhoneNumber")

The problem is there is one user reported that the extension did not pull out. It came out blank

1. I have checked on the person document and the phone number is there
2. the email address pull out correctly, but when I tested changing the first letter of first and last name to lower case (ie. Test.User@domain.com to test.user@domain.com), the field that pulls the email address still show up with Upper case.
3. I have tried to take the user.id and test it on a different PC and the problem persists.

Any idea why this happens? I know there are 2 address books set up in the company and that is not ideal but I have checked the 2 address books and make sure all the needed information are there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [@NameLookup](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/Rnext/help6_designer.nsf/f4b82fbb75e942a6852566ac0037f284/6607e1550e8e915f85256c54004c0bf0?OpenDocument) formula does a look up to a hidden view on the database, and sometimes you run into a situation where the index for that view isn't up-to-date.  You can go to the database and press CTRL+SHIFT+F9 to rebuild all the views, or you can try to use the FORCEUPDATE flag in your formula.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find that the @NameLookup call is finding people who have created entries for themselves in their personal address books.  If those entries are incomplete, the lookups will fail to find the missing fields.

Comment: I copied the user local names.nsf and put it on a different PC. Yes, I did find the user own entry in the names.nsf but even after I deleted it, re-open Notes, it is still not pulling the phone number and the email address is not the one assigned on the server.

Answer (score 0):

The @NameLookup will use the parameter...
Go to /File/Preferences/Location then is the current location find the Server Tab and check that you defined Domino Directory server (if empty user search on local)
Check also in the Mail tab, Recipient Name lookup that could "stop after first march" or exhaustively search ALL the names known on the client.
 [image]

In @NameLookup you can also use [NoUpdate]:[Exhaustive]
be aware as mention before that view may be not up to date, that caching can occurs in the @NameLookup.

In place of this, I suggest to use:

```
@DbLookup("":"";YourServer:"names.nsf" ; "($VIMPeople)" ; @Name([ABBREVIATE] ;@UserName) ; "OfficePhoneNumber");
```